# Changing Width/Gutters?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to create a thumbnail gallery with rows of 3 items and I'm not able to control the width (192px) or the gutters (10px) of the items.  Heres my code

```
    <script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('.isosort'),
        filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
      layoutMode : 'fitRows',
      animationEngine : 'best-available',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 192,
        gutterWidth: 10
      }
    });

    // filter buttons
    $('#options li ul li a').click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
      }

      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      // change selected class
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // store filter value in object
      // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
      var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
      filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
      // convert object into array
      var isoFilters = [];
      for ( var prop in filters ) {
        isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
      }
      var selector = isoFilters.join('');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

      return false;
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that to use the masonry options, you're required to choose "`masonry`" as your `layoutMode`.

Comment: I set it to masonry and it put everythign in 1 row, I've been trying to figure this out on my own for the last day with no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

I just added a possible solution to this problem at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199423/2676928

It's possible to extend/rewrite parts of isotope.  The fitRows code is comparatively simple and I added a few lines that made it support gutters and column width settings.