# Is an Isotope layout combining centered fitRows possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am attempting to set up a page on the website that utilizes a centered fitRows Isotope layout.

I can get the centered layout, and I can get the fitRows layout. However, I have not been able to combine them into a centered fitRows layout.

I am assuming there is a conflict between the centered Masonry and fitRows layouts.

Is it possible to combine these 2 types of layouts or am I out of luck? This is the first time that I've used Isotope, so I'm not sure how to do some of the more advanced tricks yet.

I'm using the following to instantiate Isotope

```
// set up isotope
var $container = $('#candidates');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.isotope({
                itemSelector:   '.candidate',
                layoutMode:     'fitRows',
                masonry:        {
                                    columnWidth:    175,
                                    gutterWidth:    20,
                                    isAnimated:     true,
                                    isFitWidth:     true
                                }
            });
    });
```

My full test code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/hightechredneckwoman/UtHRX/23/

Answer (score 4):

I just made a modified version of fitRows that may be of help:

```
  // modified Isotope methods for gutters in fitRows
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(num) {
    var resto = this%num;
    if (resto <= (num/2)) { 
        return this-resto;
    } else {
        return this+num-resto;
    }
}

   $.Isotope.prototype._fitRowsLayout = function($elems) {
    var instance = this,
          containerWidth = this.element.width(),
          props = this.fitRows;

    var gutter = this.options.fitRows && this.options.fitRows.gutterWidth || 0;
    var columnWidth = this.options.fitRows && this.options.fitRows.columnWidth ||
                  // or use the size of the first item
                  this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
                  // if there's no items, use size of container
                  containerWidth;
console.log("C="+columnWidth);
      $elems.each( function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            atomW = $this.outerWidth(true),
            atomH = $this.outerHeight(true);


    if(props.x !== 0 && props.x + atomW + gutter <= containerWidth){
        props.x = props.x.roundTo(columnWidth + gutter);
    }

        if ( props.x !== 0 && atomW + props.x > containerWidth ) {
          // if this element cannot fit in the current row
          props.x = 0;
          props.y = props.height;
        }

        // position the atom
        instance._pushPosition( $this, props.x, props.y );

        props.height = Math.max( props.y + atomH, props.height );
        props.x += atomW;

    });

};
```

It's designed to support both gutter and column width but uses the regular fitRows math for the rest of the function.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I just found and started using isotope. I've run into an issue witht he lay out where I'm trying to get my items to be in 4 columns, with 20px in between them. I'm currently acheving this with CSS and `margin-right:20px` and every 4th item is `margin-right:0;`. The problem lies when a filter is applied to my items. The 4th-item is the true 4th item, and not the 4th visible item (if that makes sense). Does the above allow for the type of customization I'm looking for? If so, how do I apply it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After inclusion of isotope javascript file add the following code to override default fitRows layout for adding centering of each row feature:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Put the following code after isotope js include
// Override and customize Isotope FitRows layout mode: CENTER each rows
var fitRows = Isotope.LayoutMode.modes.fitRows.prototype;
fitRows._resetLayout = function() {

  // pre-calculate offsets for centering each row
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.maxY = 0;
  this._getMeasurement( 'gutter', 'outerWidth' );
  this.centerX = [];
  this.currentRow = 0;
  this.initializing = true;
  for ( var i=0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++ ) {
      var item = this.items[i];
      this._getItemLayoutPosition(item);
  }
  this.centerX[this.currentRow].offset = (this.isotope.size.innerWidth +this.gutter-this.x) / 2;
  this.initializing = false;
  this.currentRow = 0;

  // centered offsets were calculated, reset layout
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.maxY = 0;
  this._getMeasurement( 'gutter', 'outerWidth' );
};
fitRows._getItemLayoutPosition = function( item ) {
  item.getSize();
  var itemWidth = item.size.outerWidth + this.gutter;
  // if this element cannot fit in the current row
  var containerWidth = this.isotope.size.innerWidth + this.gutter;
  if ( this.x !== 0 && itemWidth + this.x > containerWidth ) {

    if (this.initializing)
        this.centerX[this.currentRow].offset = (containerWidth-this.x) / 2;
    this.currentRow++;

    this.x = 0;
    this.y = this.maxY;
  }

  if (this.initializing && this.x == 0) {
    this.centerX.push({ offset: 0});
  }
  //if (this.centerX[this.currentRow].offset < 0)
  //  this.centerX[this.currentRow].offset = 0;

  var position = {
    x: this.x+(this.initializing?0:this.centerX[this.currentRow].offset),
    y: this.y
  };

  this.maxY = Math.max( this.maxY, this.y + item.size.outerHeight );
  this.x += itemWidth;

  return position;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I recently asked the Isotope author the same question on Twitter. [His answer](https://twitter.com/desandro/status/336577874721124352https://twitter.com/desandro/status/336577874721124352) was no. However, Isotope does provide a [centered masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html) layout, which might be an acceptable substitute.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, for my layout, I needed fitRows more than centered.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible for now. But you can vote for this feature here https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/579